Periodic Bell Curve?
I'm trying to code a hue selection function in a circular color model (in which each hue is attributed a value between 0 and 1) so I'm working on a Gaussian function and would like it to roundtrip between zero and one.
Basically, my function is $y(x)=\exp\left(-(x-m)^2/s^2\right)$ and I would like $y(0)=y(1)$ at all time.
I've tried something with a piecewise function but it only works if m>0.5 and s is quite small.
I haven't done proper maths in a long time and need so help to at least frame the problem correctly.
Any help would be much appreciated !
Thanks a lot
Picture explanation

I don't see how what you call "what I want to do" can be called a "Bel curve"

Otherwise said, you want to periodize this function $f$ with period $T=1$ with an explicit formula : why not using $f(t)+f(t-1)+f(t-2)+...+f(t-n)$ for $n$ large enough giving a good approximation if $s$ is large...

Something like, start with  $f(x)=\exp((1/2-x)^2)/s^2)$ and then take $$y(x)=\frac{f({x})-f(0)}{1-f(0)},$$ where  ${x}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the "fractional part of $x.$"

Another option is $y(x)=|\sin(\pi x)|,$ if you are using bell curve loosely.

$y(x)=-\exp\bigg(-\frac{\sin^2(\pi x-\pi)}{s^2}\bigg)+1$ should do the trick...
